# SocialAuthAdapter on Android - limiting the providers on share menu

Tags: android, socialauth

I am trying to integrate the social auth api for android

in **onCreate** Method :

```
    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

    adapter.addProvider(Provider.TWITTER, R.drawable.twitter);
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.LINKEDIN, R.drawable.linkedin);


    adapter.addCallBack(Provider.TWITTER, "http://XXXXXX.com/");


    try {
        adapter.addConfig(Provider.TWITTER, "XXXXX", "XXXXX",
                null);
        adapter.addConfig(Provider.LINKEDIN, "XXXXX", "XXXXX", null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This works perfectly fine sharing on linkedin, twitter

But it also list all the packages in my device, like the intent sharing - showing all the relevant packages. Is there some way to limit the options to only those listed pro-grammatically.